# How to remove a Ribbon tab which is not in the Custom tab in the Excel

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I have Excel with particular ribbon tabs. When I open Customize the ribbon Form, in the "Customize Ribbon" section, these Tab and groups are not shown in the custom tabs section, but I can see them in the "Quick Access Toolbar" section which I cannot delete them.
Thanks.

Comment: Custom controls may come from Excel add-ins or embedded in workbooks. See [Customize the ribbon in Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-ribbon-in-office-00f24ca7-6021-48d3-9514-a31a460ecb31) for more information.

Comment: This is the ribbon command and Tab which is not been removed by "reset all customizations". The question is how to create a ribbon tab and command that is not been removed by "reset all customizations".

Answer (score 0):

I used the Office RibbonX editor app and edited buttons on the XML file.